# Hover-able side navigation

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My side navigation doesn't work as expected.

**What the code should do**

1. Only display the icons when not hovered.
2. On hover display the link by displaying one letter at a time, until the entire link is visible.
3. When the hover state is no longer active the link should disappear one letter at a time time isn't not visible anymore.

I though by simply adding the `overflow-x` property would give the result I want by it isn't working.

**What is happening**

the link is displayed under the icon until the navigation's width is wide enough for the link to fit properly on the same line as the icon.

When the hover state is no longer active the link disappears immediately.

```css
nav {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.side-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 54px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 5%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  transition: width 2s;
}

.side-nav>.side-nav-top {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.side-nav>.side-nav-top>a>span:first-child {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

.side-nav i {
  color: #909090;
}

.side-nav:hover {
  width: 40%;
}

.hide {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: none;
}

.side-nav:hover .hide {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Home</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.dev.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="side-nav">
    <div class="side-nav-top">
      <a href="#"><span><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span><span class="hide">The Home page</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span><span class="hide">The Home page</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span><span class="hide">The Home page</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span><span class="hide">The Home page</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span><span class="hide">The Home page</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span><span class="hide">The Home page</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span><span class="hide">The Home page</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span><span class="hide">The Home page</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span><span class="hide">The Home page</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span><span class="hide">The Home page</span></a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `.side-nav > .side-nav-top > a` a flexbox (to prevent the *link text* wrapping below the icon) and add `white-space: nowrap` to prevent *text wrapping* of the *link text*.

Now instead of toggling display of the menu text, you can add `overflow: hidden` to the `side-nav` itslef - see demo below:

```css
nav {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
.side-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 54px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 3.5rem; /* percentage might not be a good idea here */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  transition: width 2s;
  overflow: hidden; /* added overflow here*/
} 
.side-nav > .side-nav-top > a { /* made a flexbox */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* aligns the icon and link text vertically */
  white-space: nowrap; /* prevent text wrapping */
}
.side-nav>.side-nav-top {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.side-nav>.side-nav-top>a>span:first-child {
  margin: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
}
.side-nav i {
  color: #909090;
}
.side-nav:hover {
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.dev.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
  
  <nav class="side-nav">
    <div class="side-nav-top">
      <a href="#"><span><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span><span class="hide">The Home page</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span><span class="hide">The Home page</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span><span class="hide">The Home page</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span><span class="hide">The Home page</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span><span class="hide">The Home page</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span><span class="hide">The Home page</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span><span class="hide">The Home page</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span><span class="hide">The Home page</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span><span class="hide">The Home page</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span><span class="hide">The Home page</span></a>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution like this might work for you.

You should add `overflow: hidden` on your whole `.side-nav` and disable text wrapping in `a`(or make it `flex` with `min-width`)

```css
nav {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.side-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 54px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 5%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  transition: width 2s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.side-nav>.side-nav-top {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.side-nav a {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.side-nav>.side-nav-top>a>span:first-child {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

.side-nav i {
  color: #909090;
}

.side-nav:hover {
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Home</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.dev.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="side-nav">
    <div class="side-nav-top">
      <a href="#"><span><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span><span class="hide">The Home page</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span><span class="hide">The Home page</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span><span class="hide">The Home page</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span><span class="hide">The Home page</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span><span class="hide">The Home page</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span><span class="hide">The Home page</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span><span class="hide">The Home page</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span><span class="hide">The Home page</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span><span class="hide">The Home page</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span><span class="hide">The Home page</span></a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```